# Determining Profit for 150 different Treatments Types

Tags: r, optimization, experiment-design

My objective is to show which treatment or group of treatments was most successful at generating profit.

I have a data.frame with about 7 million observations.

Each of these observations could have been in one to many of 148 different treatments. The number of treatments an observation took part in depended on how many experiments were active at the time.

In this case, an observation is a quote. It may also include a corresponding purchase of a contract.  In which case the profit will be either a positive or negative value. Only about 2.6% of quotes were purchased.

These treatments were applied to an online sales website. They used many different strategies to both improve the conversion rate from quotes to sales.  And increase the quality of contracts sold.

For example:

1. Reduced the number of pages so that prospects would have less pages to fill out to buy. *(Increase Conversion)*
2. Rearranged content so it would be more pleasing or clearly understood by prospects. *(Increase Conversion)*
3. Changed the type of payments that were accepted. *(Improve Contract Quality)*
4. Increased the amount of down payment for certain customers. *(Improve Contract Quality)*
5. Sent customized videos to the prospect after the quote. *(Increase Conversion)*

Each of these Experiments I listed above could have two or three different treatment versions. Let's say there was 50 experiments in total, each with 3 different treatment versions.  That's how we arrived at 150 different treatments.

My strategy for this analysis is to set a level playing field for all of these experiments and their corresponding treatments. When these experiments were originally run, they had many different success metrics:  Decreasing Bad Down Payments, Increasing Traffic to a Certain Page, Increasing Conversions, etc.

But again, I am trying to boil them all down and ask:  Which treatment made the most money?

The data is in the following form.

```
$ treatment_a <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0
$ treatment_b <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0
$ treatment_c <dbl> 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0
$ treatment_d <dbl> 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0
$ treatment_e <dbl> 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0
$ profit      <dbl> 2100, 0, 0, -200, 0, 500, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

The profit can be negative if money was lost on the contract.

Only 200,000 observations have a value other than zero for profit. Zero Profit in most cases means that no contract was sold for the quote.

```
> summary(final_all$Profit)
Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
-346832.2       0.0       0.0      12.2       0.0   49329.7
```

The purpose of the treatments was to both: Obtain a contract and to make money on the contract once it was established.

Some treatments could have been given to millions of observations.  Some to only thousands.

**Analysis I have done so far:**

1. Calculated the profit for each treatment separately.
2. Calculated the profit by groups who all received the same unique combinations of treatments.  There were over 2,000 groups.
3. Ordered the 2,000 groups of treatments by profit, and then looked at which individual treatments tended to be in the top earning groups and which tended to be in the bottom earning groups.

***Question #1:**

Now, I am trying to conceptualize how to compare the performance of combinations of treatments.
    Considering there are 148 different treatment types, there are over 10,000 different combinations of just two treatments.
    Should I take the first treatment and the second, then the first and the third, etc.
    Any advice here is appreciated.

***Question #2:**

Considering the data and the objective, could you recommend other types of analysis that would be beneficial?

Comment: Can you say something about the treatments? An how one or more treatments can be applied to same contract?

Comment: Kjetil - Thanks for the comment.  I have added more context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you should consider all possible combinations of treatments. Focus on the combinations that actually happen. For that matter, if there is a long tail distribution of cases across combinations, focus on the fat part first. Those cases are likely to be most subject to management. Rare but profitable cases go into the "ideas for innovation" file, just in case there is opportunity to increase their frequency over time.

Clustering to produce a dendrogram and/or heat map might provide good visual representation of which treatments tend to fall together and also their profitability. Given the options you are facing, a visual display could be helpful.

Comment: Ed thank you.  Basically you mean only concentrate on combinations that occurred in high volumes, correct?

Comment: Yes, thinking those would be most managerially relevant. But I was assuming that all records relate to the same time period. If records cover a span of time, then I think you want to sort by era, as relationships may have evolved.